# Amazon SNS invalid message structure for APNS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I've implemented Amazon SNS for push notifications.

I'm sending json in the following structure:

```
{
  "aps":{
    "alert":{
      "loc-args":["ARGS"],
      "loc-key":"KEY",
    }
    "sound":"default"
  }
}
```

But on iOS client I'm receiving it as escaped string and everything from my message is inside "alert" key

```
[AnyHashable("aps"): {
   alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"loc-args\":[\"ARGS\"],\"loc-key\":\"KEY\"},\"sound\":\"default\"}";
}]
```

I've also tried different formats from here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-custommessage.html but every-time I'm receiving the same escaped string.

Does anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Have you try `JSONSerialization` with alert value and convert it to dictionary?

Comment: Yes I've tried both escaped and not escaped. It works from Amazon SNS console, but from code it doesn't.

Comment: Can you show what you tried with notification's userInfo? Add code of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was in `publishRequest.setMessageStructure("json");` flag.
I've missed it.

Also notification should be sent in the following format:

```
{"APNS_SANDBOX":"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"loc-args\":[\"ARGS\"],\"loc-key\":\"KEY\"},\"sound\":\"default\"}}
```

Comment: This small little change, i.e. to use "json" flag finally solved my problem after so many days of searching answer to this problem. I am sending message from Android, meaning Java platform, but I couldn't find this critical piece of information documented anywhere.